# flex wrap for columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

With `flex-direction: column`, how can one layout content to wrap from one column to the next rather than stretching (and scrolling along) the same column.

I tried the following, for example, without success:

```
{
 flex-direction:column;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

In the following pen I would like the number that do not fit in the screen in column 1 to move to column 2 and so on and scroll to occur in the x direction only in case all columns get filled.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epPeoG,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `display: inline-flex;` instead of `display: flex;`. Then the columns won't stretch to the full width. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft08ncao/).

Comment: A quick follow-up if I may: What if the height of the parent container is not fixed, but is a flexbox as well (changing with window being resized, for example)? Thanks again!

Comment: Nesting flexboxes is a little buggy. The best solution I've found is having an inner wrapper with `position: absolute;` and `display: flex;`. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft08ncao/1/).

Answer (score 1):

For flex items to wrap in a column-based flex container you need to define a height for the container. Whether the height is pixels, percentage, or viewport-based doesn't matter. The flexbox just needs to know where to end the column.

Here's your codepen, modified (wrapping is based on viewport height): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPyEzZ

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;  
}
```